# pass array of object via Ajax and get as input in cotroller (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

I am doing Ajax request in a url.
I have data variable which is array of object

```
var data = [{id:1, name:'vikash'},{id:2, name:'sushant'}]

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
}).done(function (data) {
    if(data.success)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
}).fail(function (data) {
    window.showNotyError();
})
```

I want something like in controller

Input::get('something') and get the value set like laravel return after fetching a table.

Answer (score 0):

it is an array of object that you are passing to the backend so you need toloop to get the information in the array. Example

```
public function store(Request $request){
  foreach($request->all as $req){
     $model = App\Model::find($req->id);
     $model->name = $req->name
     $model->save();
  }
}
```